# Cordova web intent Plugin Not working for version 7.0.1

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, webintents

I am using Cordova version 7.0.1,I want to use webintent and when i am trying to install like this

cordova plugin add https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent.git

i am getting this error

[image]

I am trying to recieve the url from the other apps to my cordova app and the code i am following is this one.

```
 window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT, function (url) {
          alert(url);
          console.log("coming");
    }, function() { //Fail
          alert ("error");          
});
```

when i am executing i am getting this error
Error: exec proxy not found for :: WebIntent :: getExtra

**PS: I know that URL is not working,Is there any other way to install Web Intent**

Comment: If the user has pulled the repo, you'll want to [look for a mirror.](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/https-github-com-initsogar-cordova-webintent-is-404/85429/2)

Comment: again the same issue with the other links too

Answer (score 0):

That repository is no longer available.

I could successfully get the plugin from https://github.com/cordova-misc/cordova-webintent